# How to format a sed captured pattern, say \1, to print it padded with spaces

Tags: bash, sed

Suppose you have a table definition looking like this:

```
CREATE TABLE pilot (
    pi_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR,
    pi_full_name VARCHAR
);
```

which you wish transformed, for readability, to:

```
CREATE TABLE pilot (
    pi_id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    title          VARCHAR,
    pi_full_name   VARCHAR
);
```

using sed. How would you do it?

I captured the lower-case-with-underscores part coming after 4 spaces as 1st pattern, \1, doing:

```
sed -e "s/^    \([a-z_]*\)/    \1/"
```

but then i could not print it right-padded with spaces using a printf insertion:

```
sed -e "s/^    \([a-z_]*\)/    $( printf "%-14s" \1 )/"
```

as, within the printf command, pattern \1 became just 1 and this was printed:

```
CREATE TABLE pilot (
    1          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    1          VARCHAR,
    1          VARCHAR
);
```

is there a way to do it with sed? ... sigh, or other 1-liner?

Comment: Is there a good reason to choose `sed` as the specific tool? There's much more control using `awk`, or for that matter one could do the transform with native bash using no external tools at all.

Comment: (also, _grumph_ re: the "one-liner" spec -- Stack Overflow is a place for _practical_ questions; when terseness and robustness are in conflict, _practical_ real-world production systems generally call for robust solutions to be chosen over terse ones).

Comment: See https://ideone.com/DbvZ6M for an example of a native-bash approach.

Comment: (and yes, it's entirely correct and intended that you can't use command substitutions in the right-hand side of your sed replacement operations; there _is_ a GNU extension to sed that introduces an `eval` flag that can be used to work around this, but it's an invitation to horrible security bugs).

Comment: alright Charles, thank you for the comments, the only reason for using sed is that i'm better at it than awk, but i am ready to give it up on this. is there a nice awk 1-liner? [thanks for the bash solution too!]

Answer (score 2):

An (GNU) awk script might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

# less than two fields, or starts with CREATE? Do nothing at all
NF < 2 || $1 == "CREATE" { print $0; next; }

# following code block is run for each line where "next" was not called
{
  # this regex assigns $2 and onward to the variable rest
  rest = gensub(/^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*/, "", 1)
  # format $1 padded with 14 spaces, then append rest
  printf("   %-14s %s\n", $1, rest)
}
```

...or, as a one-liner from bash:

```
gawk 'NF < 2 || $1 == "CREATE" { print $0; next; } { printf("   %-14s %s\n", $1, gensub(/^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*/, "", 1)) }'
```

Comment: Happier with the 1-liner... :)  [had to use gawk instead of awk, as you did in the script-form, and had to add a missing closing ) at the end, then it works nicely... ]. Thank you!

Comment: Whoever needs to maintain it in the future would be happier if you used the non-1-liner version.

Comment: i do not disagree with that!